# Linux USB modem SMS alerts

Tags: linux, sms, at-command, modem, huawei-mobile-services

Trying to develop application using USB modem on Linux. Using Huawei E220 with CNMI=1,1,0,1,0 setup (also tried other CNMI settings none worked) and getting New Message Indications on received message to serial also on received Status delivery message. Is there any other way how to configure the device to enable received SMS alerts ? thanks Under windows machine it is working with no problems. The only problem is linux. Thank you

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of testing and trying to install many linux Mobile Partner drivers finally I came up with an idea to try communication with the modem on different serial port. Linux mounts 3 different serial devices when modem is connected and as i was comparing the modem behaviour on linux to windows i had to connect to the third mounted serial port. I absolutely do not understand why the modem is accessible on two different serial ports but i found out that only one of them can write triggers to serial console. So in case somebody would have the same problem as i had the solution is to test all available serial ports in my case it was /dev/ttyUSB2.